# When my computer boots or restarts, I see ghosts!

Tags: macos

These days, when I power-on my MacBook Pro computer, I do not see a blank display.  No... I see "ghosts" of the icons that were on the toolbar of my latest reboot.  Most recently, I've even seen "ghosts" of my most recent website display ... just before my latest "unexpected reboot."  Yes, when I look at "the desktop," I see them there.  Of course I have utterly no idea why the desktop graphic display of my desktop should have any sort of "memory," but lately here it is.

The graphics displays, as of late, have also become quite inexplicable: why should I see the ghostly remnants of the taskbar, even before my computer asks me to log in?  And then, having logged in, why should I see the ghostly remnants of a previous web page that I have visited, superimposed upon my Finder screen?

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing a photo or video of the phenomenon you're describing, two possibilities come to mind:

1. You may be seeing **[LCD image persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence)**, or "**burn in**", which is a parasitic behavior in liquid crystal displays that can occur when a static image, particularly at high brightness levels, remains on the screen for an extended period of time. Older displays are more likely to experience this. For example: [image: MacBook Air LCD image persistence during boot showing ghosted Dock and web browser]
2. You might be seeing the **unhibernation** process taking place. In order to enter hibernation, macOS writes all contents of memory onto disk before shutting off power to almost every part of the computer. In order to wake from hibernation, the prior memory contents have to be restored from disk, which takes time. To show the user that the machine is working, system firmware draws a progress bar along with a grayscale image of the screen as it looked before entering sleep. It looks like this: [image: Mac system waking from hibernation sleep and displaying progress bar on gray screen]

So does your Mac look like either of those? Can you show us a photo or video?

Comment: Parasitic? Has my screen got an infestation? ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy Well that would qualify as “buggy” behavior ;)